# Do the cells of any multicellular lifeforms discard their genetic material after differentiating?

Tags: genetics, development, differentiation

There are many types of cells which will never again divide. Some of them may not need DNA to perform their function. Are there any cases where the DNA is discarded after a final differentiation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend looking into [terminal differentiation](https://www.nature.com/articles/nrn2678).

As one extreme example of terminal differentiation, [xylem cells that form plant vascular tissues are simply dead](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:142146/FULLTEXT01.pdfProgrammed). This is a case where not only the genome but also physiologic activity in these cells is irrelevant to their function.

A more famous case is [red blood cell enucleation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2995553/), wherein the genome of mature cells is lost in cell division.

In other words, yes, this happens.

Comment: But how does this answer the question? The instance  you explain is for cells that just die — not an example of what the poster is asking about, and we have no idea from your answer what is in the review you link to. Please either explain in your answer or restrict yourself to commenting.

Comment: Your answer didn't answer the question I meant to ask, but it did answer the question I wrote in the title. Rather than say your interesting reply was unfit, I have decided to change my question to match it. I'll ask a new question about what I really meant later. :-)